# Execute perl in PHP

Tags: php, perl, shell, exec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling Perl script from PHP and passing in variables, while also using variablized perl script name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438626/calling-perl-script-from-php-and-passing-in-variables-while-also-using-variabli)

I want to execute a perl script through PHP. I use `exec()` to execute the perl script. It works in my machine but does not work on the server. The Server is based on CentOS Linux.

I gave full permission (777) to both the PHP and the perl script file. When I try to execute, I get the following error in error_log

```
sh: /perl: No such file or directory
```

I tried to execute using the following ways

```
exec("perl -w Script.pl $username $password",$output);
exec("/usr/bin/perl -w Script.pl $username $password",$output);
exec("/usr/bin/perl Script.pl $username $password",$output);
```

I also tried by using the `system` function

```
$output = system("perl Script.pl $username $password");
```

Nothing happening when I try this.

I also tried to execute perl by using the `passthru()` function

```
passthru("/usr/bin/perl -w Script.pl $username $password",$output);
```

When I execute this line, `$output` prints 127 and nothing happens in the script.

I checked whether file is executable or not with the `is_executable()` function. It shows that the file is not executable.

Code as below

```
$file = 'Script.pl';

if (is_executable($file))
{
    echo $file.' is executable';
}
else
{
    echo $file.' is not executable';
}
```

If I execute perl through the terminal, it works fine but when I try to execute through PHP, it is not working.

Comment: @K102 Sorry ya... I mistakenly typed in this post..

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for your link.. Still i have the same problem..

Comment: Perhaps you're not allowed to make any system calls from php because of some strict security settings? Check with a simple command like `ls` or `cwd`. If you only execute the perl script from the command line with the perl interpreter up front, you don't have to set the execute permission.  `664` should do. Otherwise it might be executable from a browser if the server is set up in that way.

Comment: what does the output of `exec('which perl', $output);` give you?

Comment: @Ben When i exec which perl , following error occur sh: /which: No such file or directory..

Comment: @simbabque I agree with .. when i check the phpinfo, Safe_mode is on in lOcal value and Off in Master value. i want to disable Local value of safemode. some site instruct me to disable Safe mode.. even i change the php.ini, Local value is still on. I think this is the problem.. can u help me to resolve this

Comment: Is your website hosted in a "jailed" environment? A jailed environment is one where most of the UNIX commands are disabled for security. Is perl installed (and/or enabled) in the first place?

Comment: @SalmanA Perl is installed in my server as well as enabled. when i execute perl script alone, it works fine.

Comment: I solved this problem by Disable Safe_mode in php.ini

Comment: Great. :) Post it as an answer and accept it yourself so the question is marked as completed.

Answer (score 10):

Use full path to execute the script.

```
exec("/usr/bin/perl /full/path/to/Script.pl $username $password",$output);
```

Regards,

Comment: Already i try this.. Not working.

Comment: PHP executes as the apache user `www-data`. Your script is probably needs to run as a sudo, but PHP wont allow it. At least for `debiab`, run `visudo`, and then add `www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /pat/to/your/script.pl`, then change permission so only root can edit the file (safety): `sudo chown root:someuser /path/to/your/script.pl`, and lastly make it executable `sudo chmod u+rwx /path/to/your/script.pl`